# How can I execute a java console application by using a C++ application and the system function?

Tags: java, c++, jar

I've created the jar file

it works well when I enter

java -jar file.jar

I've created a simple C++ program

```
 #include <cstdlib>

 int main(void){

   system("java -jar file.jar");
   system("pause");

  }
```

I take the exe file created by visual studio, and run it inside the directory where the jar file is

I get the following error though:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
      at java.lang.classLoader.defineClass1
      at ...
      ...

Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit

what am I doing wrong?

also, although my program has gui inside, I can't just double click on the jar file and run the program, I need to use a command line..

Comment: Which OS are you running under? Windows JRE installs updates java.exe in the Windows directory. You might be running a different version of Java than you think. Which java.exe is on the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a **RUNNABLE** jar? How are you creating your jar file? are you creating it through the command line, or are you using your IDE to export one? follow [this](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html) link if you are creating it manually, otherwise make sure you are selecting **Runnable jar** when exporting from your IDE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I'm using Runnable jar with eclipse.
In netbeans I never had any problem with creating jar files, I'm not sure why this is happening with eclipse. I will try the manual way.

Comment: just make sure everything is correct when exporting from eclipse...select runnable jar, and make sure you select the right main class.